# How can I return the values of specific integers?

Tags: vba

I would like to know how to return the value of both `intcon` and `intRed` in my function:

```
Function CountInterface(parI As String, parC As String) As String
' mes variables
    Dim strSQLQueryCountingI As String
    Dim intCon As Integer
    Dim intRed As Integer
    Dim rstCountInt As DAO.Recordset
    
    strSQLQueryCountInterface = "SELECT " _
                                & "CcProd.F_Cpr," _
                                & "CcProd.F_Int," _
                                & "Sum(CcProd.F_Re) AS Total, " _
                                & "Sum(CcProd.F_Con) As ConPost " _
                            & "FROM " _
                                & "CcProd " _
                            & "GROUP BY " _
                                 & "CcProd.F_Cpr, " _
                                & "CcProd.F_Int" _
                            & "HAVING " _
                                & "(((CcProd.F_Int) Like '" & parI & "')" _
                                & " AND ((CcProd.F_Cpr) Like '" & parC & "' )" _
                                & ") "
                               
   
     Set rstCountInt = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQLQueryCountInterface, dbOpenDynaset)
        
            intCon = CInt(rstCountInt !Connected_Post)
            Debug.Print intCon
        
            intRed = CInt(rstCountInterface!Total_Post)
            Debug.Print intRed

End Function
```

Comment: Do you want to return integers or string containg both integers?

Comment: Where do you want to return the values to?

Comment: I want to return the integers value and a wish to return them when i call them in another sub Function I'm doing

Comment: You can either create a custom type or class and have your function return that, or pass both as `ByRef` parameters.

Comment: ByRef parameters. – BigBen 9 mins ago  could you please give an example when they are declare as parameters how do I return the values in the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a custom `Type` object. For example:

The Type:

```
Public Type InterfaceType
    Connected As Integer
    Registered As Integer
End Type
```

Your method returning the above type:

```
Function ReturnInterfaceType() As InterfaceType

    Dim t As InterfaceType
    
    t.Connected = 365
    t.Registered = 400
    
    ReturnInterfaceType = t
End Function
```

To call it:

```
Sub T()

    Dim t As InterfaceType
    
    t = ReturnInterfaceType()
    
    Debug.Print t.Connected
    Debug.Print t.Registered
    
    '365
    '400
End Sub
```

---

To return`ByRef`, you need to update the method signature to accept the two variables. Since they're passed by reference, the function **can** change their values.

For example:

```
Function CountInterface(ByVal parInterface As String, _
                        ByVal parCcProductId As String, _
                        ByRef outConnect As Integer, _
                        ByRef outRegistered As Integer) As String

    '...
    
    outConnect = 365
    outRegistered = 400
    
End Function
```

To call it:

```
Sub T()

    Dim intConnect As Integer, intRegistered As Integer, s As String
    
    s = CountInterface("a", "b", intConnect, intRegistered)
    
    Debug.Print intConnect
    Debug.Print intRegistered
    
    '365
    '400
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I do to return it when the values has been pass in parameters(byRef)

Answer (score 2):

You could return them as an array.

```
Function CountInterface(parInterface As String, parCcProductId As String) As Variant
' mes variables
Dim strSQLQueryCountInterface As String
Dim intConnect As Integer
Dim intRegistered As Integer
Dim rstCountInterface As DAO.Recordset

    strSQLQueryCountInterface = "SELECT " _
                                & "CcProductid_details.F_Cc_Product_Id," _
                                & "CcProductid_details.F_Interface," _
                                & "Sum(CcProductid_details.F_Registered) AS Total_Post, " _
                                & "Sum(CcProductid_details.F_Connected) As Connected_Post " _
                                & "FROM " _
                                & "CcProductid_details " _
                                & "GROUP BY " _
                                & "CcProductid_details.F_Cc_Product_Id, " _
                                & "CcProductid_details.F_Interface " _
                                & "HAVING " _
                                & "(((CcProductid_details.F_Interface) Like '" & parInterface & "')" _
                                & " AND ((CcProductid_details.F_Cc_Product_Id) Like '" & parCcProductId & "' )" _
                                & ") "


    Set rstCountInterface = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQLQueryCountInterface, dbOpenDynaset)

    intConnect = CInt(rstCountInterface!Connected_Post)
    Debug.Print intConnect

    intRegistered = CInt(rstCountInterface!Total_Post)
    Debug.Print intRegistered

    CountInterface = Array(intConnect, intRegistered)

End Function
```

Or a dictionary.

```
Function CountInterface(parInterface As String, parCcProductId As String) As Variant
' mes variables
Dim strSQLQueryCountInterface As String
Dim intConnect As Integer
Dim intRegistered As Integer
Dim rstCountInterface As DAO.Recordset
Dim dicCounts As Object

    strSQLQueryCountInterface = "SELECT " _
                                & "CcProductid_details.F_Cc_Product_Id," _
                                & "CcProductid_details.F_Interface," _
                                & "Sum(CcProductid_details.F_Registered) AS Total_Post, " _
                                & "Sum(CcProductid_details.F_Connected) As Connected_Post " _
                                & "FROM " _
                                & "CcProductid_details " _
                                & "GROUP BY " _
                                & "CcProductid_details.F_Cc_Product_Id, " _
                                & "CcProductid_details.F_Interface " _
                                & "HAVING " _
                                & "(((CcProductid_details.F_Interface) Like '" & parInterface & "')" _
                                & " AND ((CcProductid_details.F_Cc_Product_Id) Like '" & parCcProductId & "' )" _
                                & ") "


    Set rstCountInterface = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQLQueryCountInterface, dbOpenDynaset)

    intConnect = CInt(rstCountInterface!Connected_Post)

    intRegistered = CInt(rstCountInterface!Total_Post)

    Set dicCounts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    dicCounts("Connect") = intConnect
    dicCounts("Registered") = intRegistered

    Set CountInterface = dicCounts

End Function
```